# Websphere 7 with JSF 2

Tags: java, jsf, websphere

I need to use JSF 2 for an application running under Websphere 7.0.0.13, I have followed this:

http://www.manorrock.com/online/wiki/app/page/edit.html

***It says:

```
Even though Websphere 7 does not formally support JSF 2.0 you can get it to work in a degraded mode. Follow the steps below to get it to work on your version of Websphere 7.
    Upgrade to at least version 7.0.0.13
    Ship the Mojarra JAR files in your WEB-INF/lib directory
    Set the WAR classloader to PARENT_LAST
    Set the EAR classloader to PARENT_LAST and APPLICATION
Note the degraded mode means you are NOT going to be able to use @Resource or any JPA annotations. If you think you need support for it contact your IBM representative.
Note it will process @PostConstruct and @PreDestroy.***
```

I did this, but I getting this error, in the log:

```
[8/30/13 22:51:32:702 CDT] 0000000c webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation: loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@31c031c" previously initiated loading for a different type with name "javax/servlet/ServletContext" defined by loader "org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader@66656665"
    at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(WebConfiguration.java:184)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:163)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.notifyServletContextCreated(WebApp.java:1681)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:374)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:100
```

And the error en my page:

```
Error 404: javax.servlet.UnavailableException: SRVE0201E: Servlet [javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet]: not a servlet class
```

This is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>testJSF2</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I accesed by:

```
..../testJSF2/index.faces
```

If I enter by:

```
..../testJSF2/index.jsp
```

get this in the page:

```
HTTP Error Code:   500

Error Message:

JSPG0049E: /index.jsp failed to compile : 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 48 : The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 100 : The method handlePageException(Exception) in the type PageContext is not applicable for the arguments (Throwable)
JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 20 in the file: /index.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /index.jsp 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 119 : The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 21 in the file: /index.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /index.jsp 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 144 : The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
```

Root Cause:

```
com.ibm.ws.jsp.JspCoreException: JSPG0049E: /index.jsp failed to compile : 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 48 : The method getJspApplicationContext(ServletContext) is undefined for the type JspFactory
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 100 : The method handlePageException(Exception) in the type PageContext is not applicable for the arguments (Throwable)
JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 20 in the file: /index.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /index.jsp 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 119 : The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 21 in the file: /index.jsp
JSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /index.jsp 
/opt/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer/profiles/AppSrv01/temp/wasccNode01/server4/testJSF2EAR/testJSF2.war/_index.java : 144 : The method getELContext() is undefined for the type PageContext
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.translateJsp(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper._checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:441)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.checkForTranslation(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:299)
    at com.ibm.ws.jsp.webcontainerext.AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.handleRequest(AbstractJSPExtensionServletWrapper.java:149)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3826)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
```

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2):

For WebSphere 7, I've followed another article:

http://wasbehindtheglass.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/myfaces-20-and-websphere-application.html

I've created shared library on WebSphere (name is not important, only content) with following jars:

> manifest.jar
>   myfaces-api-2.0.7.jar
>   myfaces-impl-2.0.7.jar
>   commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
>   commons-digester-1.8.jar
>   commons-collections-3.2.jar
>   commons-codec-1.3.jar
>   commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
>   \IBM\SDP\runtimes\base_v7\optionalLibraries\IBM\JSFProviders\WebSphere-MyFaces20-annotation-provider.jar

You need to give absolute paths. WebSphere-MyFaces20-annotation-provider.jar should be in your WebSphere installation. manifest.jar is the jar containing only following META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Extension-Name: org/apache/myfaces
Specification-Title: MyFaces 2.0.7 shared lib
Specification-Version: 1.0
Specification-Vendor: apache.org
Implementation-Version: 1.0
```

Final thing to be done is to modify your pom.xml to create the manifest entries referring the shared library:

```xml
<manifestEntries>
 <Extension-List>myfaces</Extension-List>
 <myfaces-Extension-Name>org/apache/myfaces</myfaces-Extension-Name>
 <myfaces-Specification-Version>1.0</myfaces-Specification-Version>
</manifestEntries>
```

After the deploy, if both shared library and manifest are configured correctly, the binding is automatically created.

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess you are not only providing the JSF classes, but a second instance / api as well.

Check if you have a servlet-api or something similar in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

As it cannot load the `ServletContext` you get the other follow-up errors. Probably even loading a simple jsp with no JSF in it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this, and it is working, just put here an alternative solution for future questions

this issue happen because we have add the servlet-api-2.5.jar in the project lib so when we remove it work . 
so here the final Step to get this work 
1- set the Parent last in the class loading policy for the application and module as well . 
2- don't add the servlet-api-2.5 .jar to the porject lib

taked from here

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014541986

Answer (score 0):

C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.3\webapps\kumar-app\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar

C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.3\lib\servlet-api.jar

I had above jar file version mismatch , i deleted the jar from C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.3\webapps\kumar-app\WEB-INF\lib\servlet-api-2.3.jar  and my application worked properly.